# why is bitcoind is missing from /usr/local/bin?

Tags: bitcoind

i just followed the instructions from degreesof zero built, made and installed bitcoind, but bitcoind was missing from the location above. What's wrong with the procedures please? thanks

https://degreesofzero.com/article/building-bitcoind-from-source-on-ubuntu.html
https://degreesofzero.com/article/installing-bitcoind-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: Your problem is probably related to xabbix's answer. If not, you could try running 'which bitcoind' and if Linux knows where it is, it will tell you.

Answer (score 3):

If you've followed the first link, you will also need to `sudo make install`, this will take the relevant binary files and place them in the `/usr/local/bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think the latest install puts bitcoind and bitcoin-cli in /usr/bin (not in /usr/local/bin).